# How do I level up just my attributes in Dragon Age: Origins (PS3)?

Tags: ps3, dragon-age-origins

Is any one still playing dragon age origins?  I need to know how I got stuck leveling up as far as attributes go?  I cant level up anymore as it seems to keep me from completing the level up after using my points.  Is it because of glicth usage or should i start over and plan the levels?

Comment: @lilserf - you beat me to the edit by 9 seconds, ahaha.

Comment: Heh, that's amusing.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of people that play it still.

To answer your question, there is a level cap on Dragon Age: Origins, sort of.

You cap at 25 and then due to a bug in the game you cannot hit 26, unless you get Awakening.

Comment: I agree - the same has happened to me. Getting awakening should solve your problem